# Text fixture setup failed on huge array

Tags: c#, xamarin, nunit

I'm trying to test my method for overflow error described [here](http://googleresearch.blogspot.ru/2006/06/extra-extra-read-all-about-it-nearly.html).
For some reason running test fails with error "TestFixtureSetUp failed".
Probably something is wrong with initializing array by using `int[int.MaxValue]`.
Can someone explain how to fix this?

```
  [TestFixture ()]
    public class FindRecursiveTest
    {

        int[] overflowArray = new int[int.MaxValue];

                [Test ()]
        public void TestOverflow ()
        {
            int[] array = overflowArray;
            int searchNumber = int.MaxValue;  
            Assert.AreEqual(-1, BinarySearcher.FindRecursive(searchNumber, array, 0,array.Length - 1), "key 0");

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class initializer is probably throwing an `OutOfMemoryException` when initializing `overflowArray`.  There's no way around it that I know of, since the maximum size of an object in .NET is 2GB

Starting with .NET 4.5 you can create *arrays* of sizes larger then 2GB by setting the [`gcAllowVeryLargeObjects`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh285054%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) setting, but the size limit still applies to other objects.